# Example of a minimal separator being strictly included in another minimal separator

Tags: graph-theory

While reading the paper "Listing all potential maximal cliques of a graph" by Vincent Bouchitte and Ioan Todinca I encountered the following statement.

> Unlike the minimal separators, a potential maximal clique $\Omega'$ cannot be strictly included in another potential maximal clique $\Omega$.

I cannot get my head wrapped around the fact that minimal separators can be strictly included in other minimal separators.

I was wondering whether someone can give me an example of a minimal separator being strictly included of another minimal separator.